# What Should be the correct Code in order to get the factorial of n?

Tags: python, numbers, factorial

What should be the correct code in order get the factorial of n?

```
n=int(input("enter a number."))
p=1
for i in range(n):
    p *= i
print(p)
```

I wanted to find out the factorial of a number but i always get 0 as output

Comment: `range(n)` includes `0`...

Comment: Simply `print(p)` in the for loop and you’ll see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just change `range(n)` to `range(1,n+1)`. As jonrsharpe commented, range includes zero, which nullifies the multiplication.